# Capture packets from WiFi to wired computer

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I have a computer and a mobile phone (Android). The computer gets a wired connection to the router/modem while the phone connects to the router/modem via WiFi.

I would like to capture all packets sent to the Internet from my phone and capture them into my computer's Wireshark. Apparently, my only option is to somehow "force" my router to redirect all of the phone's packets to my computer's IP Address, right? So, I have to somehow do something to my router's routing tables?

How exactly can I achieve such a thing by routing tables or otherwise? My router is Speedport Entry 2i.

Comment: which version of windows are you running wireshark on? & assuming you don't have a 2nd wifi router you could turn into a wifi access point & a hub to connect the 2nd router & your PC into before plugging the hub into your gateway to the internet?  wireshark hearing stuff is dependent on the connection its listening to. Hence the suggestion to route to your PC.  Using an access point (2nd wifi router in access mode) & a hub to it & your pc, means all packets are heard across the hub. Knowing which version of windows, you might set up Inet Connection Sharing on PC w/its 1 ether conn as GW 4 cell

Comment: @TG2 Windows 10 Education. I don't actually have a 2nd router... But can't I do something with the routing tables on my router's interface? I have full control of the router's interface.

Comment: if you had a wireless nic on your pc, then you could make it so the phone went through your pc for wifi. Assuming no wireless nic, there are tools (usb reverse tethering) that allow you to use Phone -> Usb -> Pc -> Internet Will depend on model of android phone.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

http://mashable.com/2015/08/18/windows-10-wi-fi-router

Turn your wireless into an AP for other devices.  Set-up a wifi network for the Cell to connect to, and then its already coming to your PC rather than to the router first.

routing to your pc isnt the problem, its *through* that is. Because your PC is "switched" you have to do something to it that will allow "promiscuous mode" to work.

Promiscuous Mode for the ethernet (or wifi) requires shared bandwidth via hub, not switched bandwidth.  In switched bandwidth the only traffic that comes to your machine is that which the switch knows is associated to your machine (nic's) MAC Address, only when a packet comes to a switch, and the mac is unknown, will the switch broadcast that packet to all ports.

In a shared network with hub, traffic heard on 1 port is broadcast to all ports, thus if the PC's nic is in promiscuous mode, it would hear everything.

Other items .. the above link to an app that is basically enabling Routing & Switching on your PC.  If you dig, you may find ways to enable it without the app, give your nic a second IP address (static ip addressing) and if so, could give your PC's new IP as the "gateway" for your phone.  either way traffic needs to flow through your PC so that the Nic listened to in Wireshark, is hearing the traffic passing though.